# didBeginContact() in SpriteKit is not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my SpriteKit Project (Swift), I use, just like everyone else, the autofill feature in Xcode. But when I type in didBeginContact, nothing comes up. I even try to type it all out like this...

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

}
```

But it just creates a bran new function. I type out this function inside a class, it is not created side another function. Has had anyone had this problem before? And does anyone know the solution?

Comment: There is no IDE that writes code inside the bracket for you.  If there were, then what would be your job?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard about the autofill feature. You have to tell the function, what to do, when somethings is making contact. For example:

```html
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    CollisionWithBullet(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Bullet: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
}

func CollisionWithBullet(Enemy: SKSpriteNode, Bullet: SKSpriteNode) {

    Enemy.removeFromParent()
}
```

This will remove the "Enemy", when it hits the "bullet". You can check out a great tutorial by Jared Davidson on youtube. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeW6SCQv--o

Comment: Not if Enemy is the secondBody and Bullet is the firstBody, it won't.